# How to implement an array of object with generic types (but different in actual type)

Tags: rust

I am quite new to Rust and I'm strugging in solving a generic type problem in a particular pattern.

Let's say I have a structure as following

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test<T>
where T: Eq
{
    pub value: Option<T>,
    pub array: Option<Vec<Test<T>>>
}
```

and I failed to use it when array contains different actual type.

```rust
fn main() {

    let a = Test {
        value:Some(16),
        array:None
    };
    
    let b = Test {
        value:Some("abc"),
        array:None
    };
    
    let c = Test {
        value:None,
        array:Some(vec![a,b])
    };
    
    println!("{:?}",c);
}
```

compiled error:

```
   |
24 |         array:Some(vec![a,b])
   |                           ^ expected integer, found `&str`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Test<{integer}>`
              found struct `Test<&str>`
```

how to change the definition of Test to achieve my goal?

Thanks.

### Some edit after adopting the answer:

while I changed to Box:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test
{
    pub value:Option<Box<dyn Eq>>,
    pub array: Option<Vec<Test>>
}

fn main() {

    let a = Test {
        value:Some(Box::new(16)),
        array:None
    };
    
    let b = Test {
        value:Some(Box::new("123")),
        array:None
    };
    
    let c = Test {
        value:None,
        array:Some(vec![a,b])
    };
    
    println!("{:?}",c);
}
```

```
5   |     pub value:Option<Box<dyn Eq>>,
    |                          ^^^^^^ `Eq` cannot be made into an object
```

### Some edit 2

by using Any trait, here compiles:

```
use std::any::Any;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test
{
    pub value:Option<Box<dyn Any>>,
    pub array: Option<Vec<Test>>
}

fn main() {

    let a = Test {
        value:Some(Box::new(16)),
        array:None
    };
    
    let b = Test {
        value:Some(Box::new("123")),
        array:None
    };
    
    let c = Test {
        value:None,
        array:Some(vec![a,b])
    };
    
    println!("{:?}",c);
}
```

output:

```
Test { value: None, array: Some([Test { value: Some(Any), array: None }, Test { value: Some(Any), array: None }]) }
```

Comment: You don't store things of different type in vectors/arrays in rust. You might want to use an enum and store that but it depends on your use case. Do you just want to store `Test<&str>` and `Test<isize>` like in the example or do you want to be able to store any `Test<T>` in `array`?

Comment: Thanks @Hadus. I like to store many types, such as i32, i16, i8, u32, u16, u8, f32, f64 and so on for comparsion purpose. If use Enum there will be lots of work to do. Anyway, if Enum is my only choice, I have to change it to enums.

Comment: If you know what types you want to use upfront you can do something like this: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=991b9ba0a199e61b5d94539878ca9071) Yes it is loads of work because it isn't easy to compare stuff that can be anything. Maybe you could store the different values as bytes that you get from serializing with serde.

Comment: This is not something that you would try to do in rust anyway. How would you use this? Or is this just a theoretical question? In which case don't try to do this in rust 

Comment: My last attempt: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d3f5fef069e32bece3c04576c3f544a) you have to run it locally because of the dependencies. It requires that the types are `Clone` and `erased_serde::Serialize` unfortunately. But there is probably a way to not need `Clone`. Essentially we serialize the value if it is the same type as the other.

Answer (score 2):

This is an error in expection. While `Test` is generic over `T`, that doesn't mean that all `Test` can be used interchangeably, without respect to what `T` actually is. In your case, `a` is a `Test<{integer}>`, while `b` is a `Test<&'static str>`. The compiler has inferred what the actual types are, filling in the blank that is the generic type parameter `T`.

In `c`, the compiler will figure out that `Vec<T>` is initialized by a `Test<{integer}` (because `a` is a `Test<{integer}`), and since all `T` for that `Vec` have to be the same, the second parameter (`b`) also has to be a `Test<{integer}>`.

You can either use an enum in the definition of `Test` to provide for both cases (`&str` and `u32` for example). Or you use dynamic dispatch, e.g. via a `Box<dyn Eq>`. However, since you are apparently going to compare values of different types, the `enum`-approach is probably the only viable, since you can't easily compare completely unknown types for equality.

Comment: Thanks @user2722968.  I like to compare values only in same type. What's the Box<dyn Eq> way to do that?

Comment: @user2722968 You cannot have `dyn Eq` because it isn't object safe! @codingchef there is no way to do it that way